How can EncodedImage Successfully Compress Image in iOS
When trying to compress images size using  EncodedImage class e.g.
EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true);

, image by Capture (camera or gallery) is compressed e.g. from size 2+MB to less than 300KB in Simulator & Android phone.
But in iPhone (iOS device) the size remains the same.
How can EncodedImage class also compress image in iOS?

This is probably due to the usage of similar quality levels in the image. I suggest using the ImageIO API directly and setting the quality parameter to a lower setting in order to tune the image size.

ImageIO.save(encodedImage, out, extension, 0.1f) compresses Images in iOS also. Thank you.

But compressed images in iOS using ImageIO are still bigger in size compared to when compressed using EncodedImage which is not working in iOS. I am inserting them to SQLite DB and therefore they should be small in size as much as possible. As I add more images in DB, the speed of loading images from DB is okay in Simulator & Android, but the speed is getting slower in iOS. How can the images be compressed further in iOS?

We use the OS facilities for encoding images, if iOS doesn't reduce the image size further then there isn't much we can do. You can scale the image down which will result in size reduction as well.

Scaling down the image using ImageIO works. But to maintain aspect ratio and quality after scaling down, Android & iOS requires different quality & scaleBy values. Android & Simulator need quality=0.9f and scaleBy=1 while iOS need quality=0.1f and scaleBy=4. Then image can be scaled using String scaledPath = ImageIO.getImage().saveAndKeepAspect(imagePath, tempPath, image.getWidth() / scaleBy, image.getHeight() / scaleBy, quality, false, false);

This way, all images size in Android & iOS taken by camera via Capture are scaled down to sizes which are less than 100KB
